# Primitive permutation groups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose that G is a primitive permutation group of degree n which contains a 3–cycle. I want to show that G contains the alternating group.

Here G being a primitive permutation group of degree n means that G is a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$ and that the only G-congruences on $\{1,\ldots ,n\}$ are trivial.

G-congruence is an equivalence relation $R$ on $\{1,\ldots ,n\}$ such that $aRb$ implies $agRbg$ $\forall g \in G$. And a trivial G-congruence means that the relation is either universal or equality.

Comment: In the definition of $G$-congruence, I don't think you want the equivalence relation to be on $G$, but rather on the objects that the elements of $G$ are permuting (for example, $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$).

Comment: Thanks, good spot. I have amended the question.

Comment: This is a standard theorem (called *Jordan's theorem*).

Comment: Thanks Steve. Do you know what ideas are used to prove this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $G$ be a primitive permutation group of degree $n$.  Assume $G$ contains a 3-cycle, say $s=(123)$.  If $G$ also contains another 3-cycle $t$ which is not disjoint from (123), then either $t$ is something like (124) which has 2 elements in common with $s$, or else $t$ is something like (145) which has only 1 element in common with $s$.  In the former case, $\langle s,t \rangle$ is all of $A_4$ and therefore contains all 3-cycles involving $\{1,2,3,4\}$, and in the latter case, $\langle s,t \rangle$ is all of $A_5$ and therefore contains all 3-cycles involving $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Therefore, if we define the relation on $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ by $$aRb {\mbox{ if either }} a=b {\mbox{ or there is a 3-cycle }} (a,b,c) \in G$$
then $R$ is a $G$-congruence.  By hypothesis, $R$ is not equality (because $G$ contains a 3-cycle), therefore, by primitivity, there is only a single equivalence class.  Therefore, $G$ contains all 3 cycles.  Since $A_n$ is generated by 3-cycles, we are done.

(Reference: This is a generalization of the argument for 2-cycles, where a primitive permutation group containing a transposition must be all of $S_n$.  See , for example, Theorem 8.17 in [Isaacs' *Finite Group Theory*](http://books.google.com/books?id=pCLhYaMUg8IC) on page 241.)

As mentioned in the comments, a more general form of this result is Jordan's theorem, which says that a primitive permutation group of degree $n$ containing a $p$-cycle where $p$ is prime and $p \le n-3$, must contain $A_n$.

Comment: +1: I was first thinking whether *primitive* can be weakened to *transitive* here. But a Sylow 3-subgroup of $S_9$ is a counterexample. So one needs an argument based on the presence of partially overlapping 3-cycles.